# Print Multiple Entries on the Same Report Line

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to make a report to go with my access database that will display the name and user id of all users.  Since the data fields do not require much space to be displayed I am trying to display multiple entries on a single line of the report so that It will look something like:

`Last1, First1 ID1 Last2, First2 ID2 Last3, First3 ID3`

Last4, First4 ID4 Last5, First5 ID5 Last6, First6 ID6

So far I have tried to use the "columns" attribute under "Page Setup", but when I tried that I either get it so that only one row appears so so it looks like:

`Last1, First1 ID1`

Last2, First2 ID2

Last3, First3 ID3

Or I would get it so that only one column would appear and look like:

`Last1, First1 ID1 Last2, First2 ID2 Last3, First3 ID3`

I have also tried to use iif statements so that each row only printed out every third entry:

`=IIf([ID] Mod 3=0,[Last Name] & ", " & [First Name] & " " & [UID] ,Null)`

This does give the entries I want, but when the Null case is returned it leaves a small gap that I do not want there.

Can anybody help me either get the columns feature working or how I can get the Null case in my statement to not create a small gap on my report?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you should consider columns : http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/multiple-column-reports-HA001156534.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I'm not sure why it worked that way but not the way I was doing it before but oh well.  As a follow up though is there a way to change the settings on columns so that the page header gets tiled across the columns as well?  As of now I have just done a simple copy paste of the labels to line them up but it would be much nicer if I could just tie them into the columns feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print a report header across all columns in MS Access 2010 using A4 210mm × 297mm based on a two column report.

1. Create your report in the normal way and switch to design view
2. Select the report header and choose columns from the page set-up tab
3. Set columns to 2 and uncheck same as detail. I prefer down the accross, but that is uo to you.
4. Select detail and set the column width to 9.55. This is calculated by 19.709cm, the page width less the margins, minus 0.635, the gutters, divided by 2 columns.
5. Squash all the detail control into 9.55cm on the left side of the page.
6. Arrange the header to suit.